# python 3.5.1 install pip

Tags: pip, python-3.5

I've been trying to figure this all day and I've reached many dead-ends so I thought I reach out to the fine people here @ stackoverflow.

Here's what I'm working against.  I've had Python 3.5.1 installed into a Linux (Linux [xxx] 2.6.9-42.0.2.ELsmp #1 SMP Thu Aug 17 17:57:31 EDT 2006 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) server I don't, or didn't at the time, have root access to.  For what ever reason PIP was not included in the installation of Python (even though ever posting I've found about installing PIP for Python >3.4 insists it's installed by default).

I've tried installing installing PIP by using GET-PIP.py, but attempts to run get-ip.py gives a long run of errors (I can provide the errors, if it makes difference).

I've tried installing PIP by using ensurepip, but I'm blocked by the following error:

python -m ensurepip
Ignoring ensurepip failure: pip 7.1.2 requires SSL/TLS

even though I have OpenSSL installed,

openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.7a Feb 19 2003

Unfortunately, I am stuck here.  I don't know why PIP wasn't included in the Python 3.5.1 build, but I need to correct this.  Any advise would be appreciated.

Dan

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I get the exact same probelm and searching for solutions here.
You can try `yum install pip`